# cómo evitar error many redirects

Tags: c#, asp.net

Tengo un código en C# para realizar la traducción de mi sitio, dependiendo la elección que se haga, acctualmente está disponible español et inglés

pero no sólo traduzco el contenido, sino que cambio el tipo de divisa

por ejemplo seleccionan Español se hace el siguiente redirect
https://beta.mexicodestinos.com/?ref=flag&co=MX&cu=MXN

y para Inglés el siguiente
https://beta.mexicodestinos.com/en/?ref=flag&co=US&cu=USD

Esto es lo que hago actualmente

masterpage

```
string enlace = Web.ChangeLinkCoin();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(enlace))
        {

            Response.Redirect(enlace);

        }
```

web.cs

```
public static string ChangeLinkCoin()
    {
        //genera la informacion basica del sitio
        string enlace = string.Empty;
        try
        {



            #region Recuperacion de variables
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["moneda"] != null || HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["cu"] != null)
            {


                string moneda = string.Empty;
                //llega en mayusculas
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["cu"]))
                    moneda = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["cu"].ToString();
                else
                    moneda = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["moneda"].ToString();

                string static_moneda = Web.obtenerMoneda();//miniscula

                if (moneda.ToLower() == "mxn" || moneda.ToLower() == "usd")
                {
                    if (moneda.ToLower() != static_moneda.ToLower())
                    {
                        Web.changeMasterCoin(moneda);
                        enlace = HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl;
                    }
                }
            }
            #endregion
            SiteInformation responeSite = new SiteInformation();
            SiteInformationBRL brl = new SiteInformationBRL();

            responeSite = brl.Start();

            //unificar campaña y pais con telefonos

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            enlace = string.Empty;
        }


        return enlace;
    }
```

pero si eligen inglés y después español, el navegador da un error como el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es un desarrollo asp.net o asp.met mvc ?

Comment: es asp.net el proyecto

Comment: entonces en la url donde esta el nombre de la pagina aspx ?

Comment: Es que depende desde donde se cambia el idioma, uso masterpages

Comment: Por favor, indica que tipo de proyecto ASP.NET es, y el **CODIGO**: Sin código es imposible responder.

Comment: Claro puedo agregar más código

Comment: que tiene que ver las master page?, eso es solo un template que se aplica sobre las aspx, la masterpage no cambia la url. Siempre se navega indicando que page.aspx quiere visualizar uses no no una masterpage

Comment: Ya dejé el código para que cheques mi procedimiento, disculpa

Comment: ya puse el código en donde hago eso pero el navegador me dice que estoy haciendo muchos redirects

Comment: y si me he dado cuenta haciendo debug que al menos pasas dos veces, pero aún así tengo la validación de si la URL es vacia o nula no debe de redirigirse

Comment: partamos de una base, sabes lo que es una master page ? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/wtxbf3hh(v=vs.100)

Comment: Si eso si lo sé ya olvida eso jajaja

Comment: Sólo fue un comentario, xD

Comment: es que defines de forma incorrecta la url sino has puesto un aspx, por eso insisto, por eso no puede resolver, salvo que estes usando Url Rewriter redefiniendo las url, pero eso deberias mencionarlo. Como tomar el "en" si este no es parte del querystring ?, lo estas poniendo comp parte de la url

Comment: el "ref", "co" y "cu" son parte del querystring, pero el "en", no lo es

Comment: a esto te refieres?

https://beta.mexicodestinos.com/en/?ref=flag&co=US&cu=USD

Comment: Por el momento no necesitamos darle importancia al en, para eso tengo un plugin que hace la traducción, el problema es que me está rediregiendo cuando regreso de un idioma al otro

Comment: Si usas asp.net clasico la url deberia ser  `http://beta.mexicodestinos.com/en/pagina.aspx?ref=flag&co=US&cu=USD`, salvo nuevamente que uses url rewriter o en realidad sea asp.net mvc

Comment: eso evitaría los muchos redirect?

Answer (score 1):

El problema por el mensaje de error es que estas entrando en un `loop recursivo` con el `Response.Redirect()`

Prueba quitar el redirect y veras si es eso lo que genera el problema.

Sino ve de poner un enlace diferente para validar que redicciona a otro sitio

Actualmente entra en un loop que redirecciona y al volver a validar redirecciona al mismo sitio entrando en un ciclo que no puede salir

Quizas se podria resolver si se valida que la url a la cual va a redireccionar es la misma en la cual ya se encuentra

```
string enlace = Web.ChangeLinkCoin();
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(enlace) && enlance != Request.Url)
 {
     Response.Redirect(enlace);
 }
```

Valida si usar `Request.Url` o `Request.Url.AbsoluteUri`

[How to get the URL of the current page in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593709/how-to-get-the-url-of-the-current-page-in-c-sharp)

Comment: hay alguna otra alternativa al response.redirect?

Comment: el IsPostBack lo podría solucionar?

Comment: no es un tema de alternativa, sino que debes ver si la logica que aplicas es la correcta, Analiza el codigo, ChangeLinkCoin devuelve un string con un enlace, si este no esta vacio redirecciona, o sea quiere decir que vuelve a pasar por ChangeLinkCoin, que si puede generar un string con el enlace redireccionar, y asi en un loop infinito

Comment: el IsPostBack  solo aplica si es una accion que genera un control de la pagina, en tu caso entra en loop ni bien ingresa

Comment: y si es !IsPostBack ?

Comment: Por otro lado yo ya hice el debug y es verdad que entra 2 veces al changeLinkCOIN pero con la validación de if, no entra dos veces al response.redirect, entonces porque dice que se redirige muchas veces?

Comment: también ya probé con session.abandon() antes del redirect

Comment: pensé también en borrar cookies antes del redirect, peor bueno, no creo que esa sea la solución

Comment: edite la respuesta, valida con esa sugerencia

Comment: Vale ya entendí cómo va el asunto